# jsTree error while giving dynamic array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am using below code to generate jsTree with jQuery 2.1.3.

```
var json = JSON.stringify(tree.nodes);
var arrayCollection = [{id:"1",parent:"#",text:"Test1"},{id:"2",parent:"1",text:"Test2"}];
$('#jstree_demo_div').jstree({
  'core': {
    'data': json
  }
});
```

If I use `json` instead of `arrayCollection` it is thowing me an error:

> > Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:  [{"id":"1","parent":"#","text":"test"}]   jQuery.min.js 2

`arrayCollection` is same and copied from `console.log(json)` but it is not working dynamically with data attribute of jsTree.

Please suggest what is going wrong here.

Comment: `arrayCollection` is a JS object. `json` is the _stringified_ version of that object. Looks like jQuery can only use the object and not the string which makes a lot of sense. Why don't you use `arrayCollection`?

Comment: I've tested with raw object tree.nodes ( Array Collection)  ,but it is not working with jsTree data.Seems that jsTree data only accept json array which I am trying in my code

Comment: so you know, I've tested this on my machine and the plugin is giving me an error: `TypeError: d.children(...).css(...).end(...).removeClass(...).addClass(...).attr(...).children(...).stop is not a function` using both your data and the example on the jstree site, so you might want to log an issue about this with the author because This isn't to do with your code as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

use `data: JSON.parse(json)` instead of `data: json`